# Laravel validate long number

Tags: laravel

i can validate numeric and integer inputs, but i can not validate long number such as `1234567891011124587`, in this validate the input value must be number not numberic.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['order_id' => 'required|digit|min:10|max:19|unique:report_transactions']);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    echo json_encode(['code'=>'-104','message'=>implode($validator->errors()->all())]);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-digits-between

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['order_id' => 'required|digits_between:10,19|unique:report_transactions']);
```